# Are there differences between the runway lighting on a land runway and on an aircraft carrier?

Tags: runways, aircraft-carrier, airport-lighting

How are the lights on aircraft carriers placed and are there differences to the color/position/number of lights at normal airports?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, basically just (dim) Edge and Centerline lights plus the IFLOLS

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Others may disagree, but I think this could be half of a good answer :-) If you can add an image of a regular runway, that would make it very easy to compare the two lighting configurations, which I believe is the basic question.